# Connect 2 Spark instances on 2 remote networks

Tags: apache-spark, cassandra, cloud

I would like to join data stored on premise DBs and data stored on cloud (ex Amazon AWS Cassandra). 
The join should be performed only on premise network.
How can i achieve this?

- 1 : Deploying Spark on premise and connecting it to local DB servers and to remote Cassandra Cloud instance and joining data in a single Spark context. It fits the requirement but imply massive data transfer from cloud to the on premise network and it gives no sense to the architecture that involve queries with high volumes of data.
- 2 : Deploying Spark on cloud on the same Cassandra nodes and read data from the remote On-Premise db into the Cloud Spark context. 
  It removes the issue on data transferring (on premise DB contain low volume of data) but it exposes on-Premise data on unsecured Cloud environment.
- 3 : ?

This is the process:
Web UI -> Java API -> Cloud Cassandra Join On Premise Database made on a Spark Instance -> Java API Create json result-> Web UI
thanks!

Comment: Do you have any on premise ETL tools ?

Comment: How frequent this operation performs ? does your local and remote DB are same ?

Comment: the join has to be perfomed by online respondding to query made by a java api that send a json to a web ui:

Web  UI -> Java API -> Cloud Cassandra Join On Premise Database made on a Spark Instance -> Java API -> Web UI